# JPA Criteria API on ManyToOne optional relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to do a simple query using JPA Criteria API on following structure

1) Employee

```
    public class Employee {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID", length = 64)
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "NAME", length = 512)
        private String name;

        @ManyToOne(optional = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID", nullable = true)
        private InternalOrg organization;

    }
```

2) InternalOrg

```
    public class InternalOrg {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID", length = 64)
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "ORGANIZATION", length = 512)
        private String organization;

        @Column(name = "CODE", length = 64)
        private String code;

    }
```

3) Query

```
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Employee> cq = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
    Root<Employee> emp = cq.from(Employee.class);

    cq.where(cb.or(emp.get(Employee_.organization).isNull(),
            cb.equal(emp.get(Employee_.organization).get(InternalOrg_.code), "1")));

    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

As you can see "organization" attribute on Employee is optional. What I'm trying to do is a query using criteria API that returns all records where "employee.organization" is NULL or "employee.organization.code" is equal to a parameter. How do I proceed?

I did some tests and realized that if I change from this:

```
    cq.where(cb.or(emp.get(Employee_.organization).isNull(),
            cb.equal(emp.get(Employee_.organization).get(InternalOrg_.code), "1")));
```

To this:

```
 cq.where(cb.or(emp.get(Employee_.organization).isNull()));
```

It works but only returns records where organization is NULL.

If I change to this:

```
cq.where(cb.equal(emp.get(Employee_.organization).get(InternalOrg_.code), "1"));
```

Records where employee.organization is NULL are ignored.

How do I return employees which organization satisfies criteria AND employees where organization IS NULL?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please add your criteria query.

Comment: Hello @ZakiAnwarHamdani, just updated my questions with more details.

Comment: I do not see any column "ORG_ID" mentioned inyour @JoinColumn specification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

finally found the solution.

The only way to create get desired result is to fetch (JoinType.LEFT) relationship earlier, here is the final criteria query:

```
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Employee> cq = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
    Root<Employee> emp = cq.from(Employee.class);

    emp.fetch(Employee_.domain, JoinType.LEFT);

    cq.where(cb.or(emp.get(Employee_.organization).isNull(),
            cb.equal(emp.get(Employee_.organization).get(InternalOrg_.code), "1")));

    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Thank you for support!

Comment: what is domain in fetch?

Comment: It's a field in Employee entity

Comment: I wonder why you fetch `domain`, when it's the `organization` that you reference in the WHERE clause. That's odd! I had to use the same column in both cases.

Comment: Because it is a lazy field and it must be loaded in this query but if it is NULL, Employee must be returned anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Conditions that are set by calling the CriteriaQuery.where method can restrict the results of a query on the CriteriaQuery object. Calling the where method is analogous to setting the WHERE clause in a JPQL query.

Example:

```
EntityManager em = ...;
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();    
CriteriaQuery<Employee> cq = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
    Root<Employee> emp = cq.from(Employee.class);
    cq.where(emp.get(Employee_.organization).isNull());
```

To specify multiple conditional predicates, use the compound predicate methods (and/or/not) of the CriteriaBuilder interface.

```
cq.where(emp.get(Employee_.organization).isNull())
.or(cb.eq(emp.get(Employee_.organization.code), "ABC"));
```

---

**Update:**

Try this:

```
cq.where(
  cb.or(
    cb.isNull(emp.get(Employee_.organization)),
    cb.equal(emp.get(Employee_.organization).get(InternalOrg_.code), "1")));
```

Comment: Hello @Cam, yes, I'm doing exactly what you sugested. The problem here is that generated query does check if employee.organization = organization.id. Because of this, records where employee.organization is NULL, it is not being returned.

Comment: Now I updated question with some additional details.